Uso AppBar no Flutter com duas linhas e a segunda é opcional
Uso AppBar no Flutter com duas linhas e a segunda é opcional, só que não sei como tirá-la quando ficar em branco, neste caso gostaria que a primeira linha ficasse centralizada na vertical. Uso o segundo fonte:
appBar: AppBar(
          title: RichText(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            text: TextSpan(
                text: unitglob.tordescri,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '\n${unitglob.torsubtit}',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ),

Alguma dica?
